# how to increase joomla article hit counter when accessing via sql?

Tags: database, joomla, counter, hit

on my joomla page i have a menu point that gives me the latest article, i wrote an extension for that. it works well, but for obvious reasons the article hit counter is not updated.

how can i fix that?

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `#__content` WHERE `catid` = {$catid} AND `state` = 1 AND publish_up <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 hour) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

for the output:

```
echo ($rows[0]->introtext);
echo ($rows[0]->fulltext);
```

Comment: You would just have to run an update query after this, with the same where clause, that sets `hits = hits + 1`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the `JTable` class

```
$table = JTable::getInstance('Content');
$table->hit($rows[0]->id);
```